# up2date not finding local rpm to install

Tags: rhel4, up2date

I need to maintain an ancient RHEL 4 server. I would like to install `tmux` but for some reason `up2date` is not finding the file:

```
[root@378911-www2 tmux]# ls
tmux-1.6-1.rf.src.rpm
[root@378911-www2 tmux]# up2date -k . tmux-1.6-1.rf.src.rpm
Fetching Obsoletes list for channel: rhel-i386-es-4...
Fetching Obsoletes list for channel: rhel-i386-es-4-extras...
Fetching Obsoletes list for channel: rackspace-rhel-i386-es-4-php-5.2...
Fetching Obsoletes list for channel: rackspace-rhel-i386-es-4-common...
Fetching Obsoletes list for channel: el4-updates...
Fetching rpm headers...

Name                                    Version              Rel               Arch
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The following packages you requested were not found:
tmux-1.6-1.rf.src.rpm

[root@378911-www2 tmux]# pwd
/root/tmux
[root@378911-www2 tmux]# up2date -k /root/tmux tmux-1.6-1.rf.src.rpm 

Fetching Obsoletes list for channel: rhel-i386-es-4...
Fetching Obsoletes list for channel: rhel-i386-es-4-extras...
Fetching Obsoletes list for channel: rackspace-rhel-i386-es-4-php-5.2...
Fetching Obsoletes list for channel: rackspace-rhel-i386-es-4-common...
Fetching Obsoletes list for channel: el4-updates...
Fetching rpm headers...

Name                                    Version              Rel               Arch
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The following packages you requested were not found:
tmux-1.6-1.rf.src.rpm
[root@378911-www2 tmux]#
```

Why might `up2date` be unable to find the file? I have tried installing with the filenames `tmux-1.6-1.rf.src.rpm`, `tmux-1.6-1.rf.src`, `tmux-1.6-1.rf`, `tmux-1.6-1`, `tmux-1.6`, a `tmux`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because won't install source rpm's ?
Even if you install it, tmux-1.6-1.rf.src.rpm is only the source, so you won't have tmux installed.
Download the binary package (or rebuild the source package downloaded with rpmbuild)

Comment: Thank you Sandor. Even trying with the `tmux-1.2-1.el4.rf.i386.rpm ` file, I kept getting the `The following packages you requested were not found` response.

Comment: Then install with rpm (rpm -ivh tmux-1.2-1.el4.rf.i386.rpm )